# Set of Automorphism of C

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove if an entire function f belongs to Aut(C), the set of all the Automorphisms of C if  and only if there is a,b belongs to C where a is non zero with f(z)=az+b.
I have shown that if f is a proper entire function then must be a polynomial. But it didn't help me at all. So what should I do to solve this problem.

Comment: I would extend $f$ to $\hat{\mathbb{C}}=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$, and show that $\infty$ is a simple pole of $f$.  This immediately implies that $f$ is a linear polynomial.

Comment: Equivalently, let $c= f^{-1}(0)$. Then $g(z) = \frac1{f(\frac{1}{z}-c)}$ is entire.